# How to get accurate idft result from opencv?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I use cv.dft to process an image and cv.idft to get it back following the tutorial [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_transforms/py_fourier_transform/py_fourier_transform.html). However, the final image has very large gray value, which is much more than 255.

I check the code and find the enlargement comes from nowhere.

How does this happen? Can I get the accurate value back?

Code for reproducing:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test.bmp',0) # change for your own test image

dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img),flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift)
img_back = cv2.idft(f_ishift)
img_back = cv2.magnitude(img_back[:,:,0],img_back[:,:,1])

print (img_back.max(), img_back.min()) # too large!!!!

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img_back, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Magnitude Spectrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to point you to the OpenCV documentation on the `cv2.idft` function:  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#idft .  There is a note at the end of it, which says:

> Note: None of `dft` and `idft` scales the result by default. So, you should pass `DFT_SCALE` to one of `dft` or `idft` explicitly to make these transforms mutually inverse.

What you are doing right now is taking the DFT and IDFT **without** accounting for the scale that allows both of the transforms to be invertible.  As such, when you call `cv2.idft`, make sure you pass the `cv2.DFT_SCALE` flag.

In other words:

```
img_back = cv2.idft(f_ishift, flags=cv2.DFT_SCALE | cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT)
```

Because your image was already real-valued to begin with, it's a good idea to pass the `DFT_REAL_OUTPUT` flag as well to ensure that your inverse is also real-valued.  All you're doing is computing the FFT, then the inverse of the result, so if you want to check to see that they're equivalent, make sure you do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have read the document more carefully.